# Need to remove emoji's and simple icons from input with javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to replace emojis and other characters such as the ♥ with nothing on keyup of an input:

```
'keyup': function() {
    this.value = this.value.replace(/\W+/g, '');
```

I would like all characters with accents to pass. I would also like punctuation to pass. Only emojis and symbols such as ♥ should be replaced.

Comment: "I would like all characters with accents to pass."  You're going to have a bad time.  The most common [UTF-8 character sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=UTF-8#Description) start with binary `110` which corresponds to accented characters in most code pages.  Differentiating between a single-byte accented character and the starting byte of a UTF-8 sequence will be challenging.

Comment: @Mr.Llama: This is JavaScript - String in JavaScript is a sequence of 16-bit code units. Encoding of the source page is irrelevant here, since the strings in the source are logically view as UCS-2/UTF-16 string in JavaScript.

Comment: @nhahtdh - Huh, today I learned something new!  Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the opposite for your regex by doing:

```
'keyup': function() {
    this.value = this.value.replace(/[^\w.,\s]/g, '');
             Replace those that are not --^
             words, dots, comma, spaces...
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

And then add all the characters you want to allow in the character class. I left letters, `_`, `.`, `,` and spaces as valid but you can add what you consider valid.

Found these list of Polish characters:

```
Ą \u0104
Ć \u0106
Ę \u0118
Ł \u0141
Ń \u0143
Ó \u00D3
Ś \u015A
Ź \u0179
Ż \u017B
ą \u0105
ć \u0107
ę \u0119
ł \u0142
ń \u0144
ó \u00F3
ś \u015B
ź \u017A
ż \u017C
```

So, you can use this code which allows polish characters too:

```
'keyup': function() {
    this.value = this.value.replace(/[^\w.,\s\u0104\u0106\u0118\u0141\u0143\u00D3\u015A\u0179\u017B\u0105\u0107\u0119\u0142\u0144\u00F3\u015B\u017A\u017C]/gu, '');
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Matching unicode with javascript might not be as straightforward as we think, so in **[this like](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-unicode#regex)** you can check a deeper explanation.

A code sample about matching unicode with regex is:

```
/foo.bar/.test('foobar')
// false

/foo.bar/u.test('foobar')   // Notice the `u` (unicode flag)
// true
```

Update: as *[CLaFarge](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1104068/clafarge)* pointed in his comment if you need the unicode block for emoticons the range is `1F600-1F64F`

Comment: That's looking good, however characters such as the polish ę should also be allowed

Comment: @beingalex I see, good point... I don't remember good enough unicode regex but you should look for unicode ranges to be used in character class

Comment: @beingalex updated my answer, it should be ok for Polish characters too.

Comment: Hey Fede, I don't know JS too well, is the UTF-16 construct \uxxxx allowed it JS ? It is Windows so, probably guessing _yes_.

Comment: The Unicode block for Emoicons is 1F600-1F64F. I hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

With the [XRegExp library Unicode plugin](http://xregexp.com/plugins/), you can use Unicode character classes in JavaScript.

`\p{S}` matches all symbols.

```
var regexp = XRegExp('[\\p{S}\\p{C}]');
this.value = XRegExp.replace(this.value, regexp, '');
```

The following character classes are defined:

```
{
    L: "Letter",
    Ll: "Lowercase_Letter",
    Lu: "Uppercase_Letter",
    Lt: "Titlecase_Letter",
    Lm: "Modifier_Letter",
    Lo: "Other_Letter",
    M: "Mark",
    Mn: "Nonspacing_Mark",
    Mc: "Spacing_Mark",
    Me: "Enclosing_Mark",
    N: "Number",
    Nd: "Decimal_Number",
    Nl: "Letter_Number",
    No: "Other_Number",
    P: "Punctuation",
    Pd: "Dash_Punctuation",
    Ps: "Open_Punctuation",
    Pe: "Close_Punctuation",
    Pi: "Initial_Punctuation",
    Pf: "Final_Punctuation",
    Pc: "Connector_Punctuation",
    Po: "Other_Punctuation",
    S: "Symbol",
    Sm: "Math_Symbol",
    Sc: "Currency_Symbol",
    Sk: "Modifier_Symbol",
    So: "Other_Symbol",
    Z: "Separator",
    Zs: "Space_Separator",
    Zl: "Line_Separator",
    Zp: "Paragraph_Separator",
    C: "Other",
    Cc: "Control",
    Cf: "Format",
    Co: "Private_Use",
    Cs: "Surrogate",
    Cn: "Unassigned"
}
```